# pyqt4 python QT global

Tags: python, qt, global

I wrote very simple python & Qt code.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(619, 501)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 460, 98, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 410, 78, 27))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox"))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2 = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 410, 78, 27))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox_2"))
        self.comboBox_2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 380, 81, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 380, 91, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "BASLA", None))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "780", None))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "1350", None))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "1850", None))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "64", None))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "128", None))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "256", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "USRP FRQ", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "FFT BOYUTU", None))

    def deger(self):
        self.us=int(self.comboBox.currentText()) 
        #print "USRP Frekansı",self.us
        self.fft=int(self.comboBox_2.currentText()) 
        #print "FFT Boyutu",self.fft

    def basla(self):
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.deger)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    ui.basla()
    Form.show()
    print ui.us   
    app.exec_()
```

When I'm running the program, I get an error message.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./dene.py", line 88, in 
    print ui.us
AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'us'.

I tried :

```
def deger():
     global us
     us=int(comboBox.currentText())
```

I am getting the following error at this time.:

File "./tt2.py", line 71, in 
    print us
NameError: global name 'us' is not defined

What could be the cause of this error?
How do I avoid this error?
Help me, Please

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use globals.

On your problem. 
You get import error because self.us is not assigned before your print statement (you didn't call method "deger").
Anyway, you should create ui files using PyQt ui generator, then you wouldn't have such errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have altered a bit your code. Now it doesn't give an error message anymore, and you get the contents of the combo boxes printed when you click the button.
If you still have any problems, please let me know. I would be happy to help you.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.us = None

    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(619, 501)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 460, 98, 27))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 410, 78, 27))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox"))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2 = QtGui.QComboBox(Form)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 410, 78, 27))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("comboBox_2"))
        self.comboBox_2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.comboBox_2.addItem(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 380, 81, 21))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 380, 91, 21))
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "BASLA", None))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.buttonAction)
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "780", None))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "1350", None))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "1850", None))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(0, _translate("Form", "64", None))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(1, _translate("Form", "128", None))
        self.comboBox_2.setItemText(2, _translate("Form", "256", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "USRP FRQ", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "FFT BOYUTU", None))

    def deger(self):
        self.us=int(self.comboBox.currentText()) 
        #print "USRP Frekansı",self.us
        self.fft=int(self.comboBox_2.currentText()) 
        #print "FFT Boyutu",self.fft

    def buttonAction(self):
        print("The button has been clicked")
        print("Text in comboBox 1: " + self.comboBox.currentText())
        print("Text in comboBox 2: " + self.comboBox_2.currentText())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtGui.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    print(ui.us)   
    app.exec_()
```